# Mount fileshare readwrite except one subdir

Tags: azure, ubuntu, mount, azure-storage-files

I have a Azure FileShare which I'd like to mount to a Azure Ubuntu 16.04 VM.
The FileShare has a structure like this:

```
myShare/
├── dirA/
│   ├── subDirAA/
│   └── subDirAB/
├── dirB/
│   ├── subDirBA/
│   └── subDirBB/
└── dirC/
    ├── subDirCA/
    └── subDirCB/
```

I want `subDirAA` to be `ro`, but everything else should be `rw`.
Do I have to mount `subDirAA`, `subDirAB`, `dirB` and `dirC` separately or is there any better solution to achieve this (like just mount `myShare` rw and then tell *somehow* that subDirAA is ro)?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, this is not possible. Azure does not support sub directory permission. If you want to set your fileshare `rw` permission, you could mount `sudo mount -t cifs //<>.file.core.windows.net/shuifile /home/test -o vers=3.0,username=<>,password=<> dir_mode=0666,file_mode=0666,sec=ntlmssp` I think one solution is that you create two Azure Fileshare and set different permissions.

Comment: I test soft link `ln -sf` in my lab, but it does not work.